# Make executable not named a.out?

Tags: gcc

For example if I run `gfortran filename.f90` it will create `a.out`, but I'd like `filename.out` instead.

Comment: Use the `-o` flag to the compiler. The `a.out` is the name the _assembler_ gives to its output.

Answer (score 5):

If you need a filename other than the default `a.out` then you must pass the desired filename after the `-o` argument to the GCC tool.

```
gfortran filename.f90 -o filename.out
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the -o option to allow you to specify an output file name.

More info on the man page, eg:

http://linux.die.net/man/1/gfortran

Answer (score 0):

`gfortran` shares a lot of command line options with `gcc` - see here:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.1/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options